# Check if variable exists in a html table with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have two tables at the moment. What Im looking to achieve is to select a row in one table, obtain the "filename" field from that and then check if that filename exists in the other table. If the file exists in both tables I want to change the colour of my progress tracker. Right now I have the selecting of the row working, but I can't seem to check it against the other table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>--</td>
    <td>Filename</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Example1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Example2</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>--</td>
    <td>Filename</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Example1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="words">
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#table").find("tr").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    var value=$(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html();
    //alert(value);
    document.getElementById("words").innerHTML = value;
});
```

Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Posting the actual HTML would be helpful to provide a better answer, or post a link to a JSFiddle of what you've got so far.

Comment: `if ($('#table2 td:contains(' + filename + ')').length) // do stuff`

Comment: Sorry I just added the HTML, the fields are being populated from files using php so I can't really show a lot of whats happening

Comment: I'll upvote your question, since it's difficult to do certain things when you're new, but this site is set up to protect from spammers/scammers.  You can also think about changing your username.  A few upvotes should be all you need to comment and do other things.

Comment: Thanks a lot @vol7ron!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pete commented, you can use `if ($('#table2 td:contains(' + value + ')').length)` as follows

```
$("#table").find("tr").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
    var value=$(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html();
    //alert(value);
    if ($('#table2 td:contains(' + value + ')').length) {
        document.getElementById("words").innerHTML = value;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("words").innerHTML = "false";
    }
});
```

See the JSFiddle for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/v14L4bqr/

Comment: *contains is probably the better choice, for some reason I thought it was deprecated*

Comment: you oculd also use .filter()

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks for your help, I can't vote it up until I get a reputation of 15 but I'll be sure to do it as soon as I do!

Comment: No problem. If it helped, I think you can accept it as answer after sometime. :)

Comment: @user you can select it as an answer; you and Kishor will receive points once you do

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise I could do that! I've done it there now, Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#table").on('click','tr',function(){                   // <-- #1
   var $this    = $(this),                                // <-- #2
       filename = $this.find('td:nth-child(2)').text(),   // <-- #3
       $words   = $('#words');

   $this.addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
   $words.html(filename).css('color','black');

   if ( valueInTable('table2', 1, filename ) ){           // <-- #4
     $words.css('color', 'blue');
   }

});

function valueInTable(tableID, columnNum, searchString){
  var found = false;
  $( '#' + tableID + ' tr td:nth-child(' + columnNum + ')' ).each(function(){
    if ($(this).text() == searchString ){
      found = true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  return found;
}
```

1. This is important, this binds the event to the table.  When a click occurs somewhere inside the table it checks the event registry, in this case, it checks to see if a TR was clicked.  This is both a performance gain, since you're not creating an event for each row of the table, but also if you create new rows dynamically, you don't have to create a new event when you do.  You create this event once and it's in place for all new/old rows of the table
2. Cache `$(this)` into a variable.  You use it more than once and chances are you'll use it even more.  You should not create a new jQuery object every time you want to refer to `$(this)`, so stick it in a variable and reuse that
3. While `.html()` may work for you, if you have other embedded HTML, you might get values you were not intending (e.g., `<span>filename</span>`), for that reason, you only need `.text()`, which will just give you the text value and strip off all the nested HTML (leaving you with only `filename`)
4. Using a function comes with a penalty, but it's good to put long-logic elsewhere, in case you're doing anything more involved.  For instance, your table could expand in width (number of columns) and you might also want to search them for a value, or you might have more tables you want to look in; this same function can be used for both of those cases.

*as noted, the `:contains()` selector was built for what you're after*  However, there is one caveat.  The problem with contains is that it lacks customization.  If you want to modify your comparison to be a RegEx, or if you want to perform other manipulation using trim or truncate, you can't do that with contains.  You could easily modify the code below to do: `$.trim( $(this).text() ) == $.trim( searchString )`

Comment: @user please refer to this edit as it points out changes that are worth consideration, which were present, but not outlined/described beforehand.  There are many other things I could have done, but this I kept the number of changes low, since it's a quick learning tool going forward.  That said, if you are new to the language, you already have demonstrated better understanding than some other seasoned developers